# How to disable Flycheck when editing in sudo?

Tags: flycheck

Sometimes I want to edit a file in Emacs as root. So I found this useful function:

```
(defun sudo-edit (&optional arg)
  "Edit currently visited file as root.
With a prefix ARG prompt for a file to visit.
Will also prompt for a file to visit if current
buffer is not visiting a file."
       (interactive "P")
       (if (or arg (not buffer-file-name))
           (find-file (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:"
                              (ido-read-file-name "Find file(as root): ")))
         (find-alternate-file (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:" buffer-file-name))))
```

But I'm not able to save the file, I got the following error message:

> Suspicious state from syntax checker emacs-lisp: Flycheck checker
>   emacs-lisp returned non-zero exit code 255, but its output contained
>   no errors: Opening input file: No such file or directory,
>   /sudo:root@localhost:/etc/mysql/flycheck_my.cnf

This problem is understandable. In order to get `flycheck`-package (an alternative to Flymake) working, it tries to create the file `flycheck_my.cnf` in directory `mysql`, but it don't have any write access in order to create the file.

So I modified the function as following:

```
(defun sudo-edit (&optional arg)
  "Edit currently visited file as root.

With a prefix ARG prompt for a file to visit.
Will also prompt for a file to visit if current
buffer is not visiting a file."
       (interactive "P")
       (if (or arg (not buffer-file-name))
           (find-file (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:"
                              (ido-read-file-name "Find file(as root): ")
                              (flycheck-mode nil)
                              ))
         (find-alternate-file (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:" buffer-file-name))
         (flycheck-mode nil)
         ))
```

But I keep the same error message, while the flycheck-mode is disabled. So somewhere I went wrong. But where? And why?

Comment: I don't think the flycheck-mode calls are right - the docs say "When called from Lisp, enable ‘flycheck-mode’ if ARG is omitted, nil or positive." so those calls will be turning flycheck mode on. I don't have flycheck mode being enabled by default - are you using global-flycheck-mode?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So if I understand you right, my function enables the flycheck mode on. I checked, and `global-flycheck-mode` is disabled. I still got the same error.

Comment: Yeah, I think you need to use `(flycheck-mode -1)` to turn flycheck off, but if you've not got `global-flycheck-mode` enabled I don't see why it should be on at all.  I also suspect that flycheck is being enabled (by whom we don't know) when the file is visited before it even gets to your lines for turning it off...

Comment: You're right. Disabling `(flycheck-mode -1)` and `(global-flycheck-mode -1)` helped me in this case.